# Is it possible to get a ip address of connected access point?

Tags: java, android, server

Is it possible to get a ip address of connected access point?

Lets say my android phone will be the client, and my raspberry pi will be the server. My raspberry pi is set up as a stand alone network access point.

When my android phone is connected by wifi to the raspberry pi, I would like to know the ip address of the raspberry pi.

I've searched numerous times, but most of the time, it is getting the ip address of the client from the server side.

Comment: User some fixed IP, or an DNS in your Lan.

Comment: If you've already connected to the pi, then you already know the address, because you had to use it to connect.

Comment: [`Socket.getInetAdress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress--)?

Comment: Uhhmm, the thing is i know the pi's address, however i wanna make this dynamic, so once they are connected by wifi, from the wifi connection, i want the android phone to be able to identify the remote ip address and then use that address to set up a TCP connection with the pi

Comment: What do you mean "connected by Wifi"?  Wifi only connects your phone to a router or something, and allows access to the server which will also be connected to the same network.  Your phone will not be connected to the server "by wifi", only by TCP.

Comment: @SteveSmith I set up my raspberry pi as a stand alone network access point. So it kinda acts like a hotspot. My android phone is connected to the hotspot via wifi

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense.  I've had a quick google myself and I don't think it will be easy, and probably involve running commands on the Pi.  BTW, I'd edit your question to indicate that the Pi is the access point.

Comment: https://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-an-access-point-422 any good?

Comment: @SteveSmith yup, i edited my question, it was pretty misleading. Hmm, actually, i wanted to find out the ip address programmatically, and not by running on the command prompt. If it is impossible to do so, looks like i will have to use the static ip of the raspberry pi. I was really hoping that my android device could automatically discover the ip address for me

Comment: You don't need to use the command prompt, you can use something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mycommand");` and then read the output, all programatically.  You just need to find out what program to run to get the details you are looking for. :)

Comment: It is just the gateway of your wifi connection.

Comment: @greenapps so i can get the raspberry pi ip address, by getting the gateway of my wifi?

Comment: That is what i suggested yes. But meanwhile you will have tried that out isnt it?

Comment: @greenapps not yet, probably in the next week! For now i will just use the hardcoded ip address to continue with my project.